# replace a part of data.table with a vector

Tags: r, replace, data.table

I have a data table that can be created by

```
top_m_dt = data.table(future_fip = c(102, 104, 503),
                  model = c("model_1", "model_2", "model_3"),
                  time_period = c("F1", "F2", "F3"),
                  emission = c("emission_1", "emission_2", "emission_3"),
                  top_1_fip = c(666, 666, 666),
                  top_2_fip = c(666, 666, 666),
                  top_3_fip = c(666, 666, 666))
```

I would like to replace row 1 and columns `top_1_fip`, `top_2_fip`, `top_3_fip`
with a set of values, lets say `c(10, 20, 30)`.

None of the followings work:

```
top_m_dt[1, c("top_1_fip", "top_2_fip", "top_3_fip")] <- 
    as.numeric(analog_dat_F1$analog_NNs_county[1:3])`
```

OR

```
top_m_dt[1, 5:7 ] <- list(analog_dat_F1$analog_NNs_county[1:3])[[1]]
```

OR

```
top_m_dt[1, (c("top_1_fip", "top_2_fip", "top_3_fip")):= 
             analog_dat_F1$analog_NNs_county[1:3]] `
```

They all replace `10` in all three locations. any suggestions?

Comment: Your example code doesn't run---do you mean to have each of the `target_fip` and `model_n` and `emission` values in quotes?

Comment: Sorry, the last parentheses was left out of {code} mode!
And, OK, those emissions have values in my computer! so, yeah, lets put quotes on them. sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.table` syntax is bit different and not everything that works on a dataframe works on `data.table`. In this case to replace values from specific row and column you could use `as.list`

```
library(data.table)
top_m_dt[1, c("top_1_fip", "top_2_fip", "top_3_fip") := as.list(c(10, 20, 30))]

top_m_dt
#   future_fip   model time_period emission top_1_fip top_2_fip top_3_fip
#1: target_fip model_n          F1 emission        10        20        30
#2: target_fip model_n          F2 emission       666       666       666
#3: target_fip model_n          F3 emission       666       666       666
```

Comment: I was missing `as.` before the `list`. This shit is sensitive to everything!